# Fetching all the csv filenames from HDFS directory using spark/scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Can someone please guide me how can i take only  .csv file from  my HDFS directory using scala.
I'm tring to fetch all the csv file name from my hdfs location and writing below code.

```
    var Fsys1 = FileSystem.get(sparksession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    var FileNames = Fsys1 .listStatus(new  Path("hdfspath").filter(_.isFile).map(_.getPath.getName).toList
```

it giving me all the files names,but i want to fetch only .csv files.

Comment: .filter(_.toLowerCase.endsWith(".csv"))

Answer (score 0):

As @pasha701 mentioned in the comments. You can filter files ending with ".csv"

.filter(_.toLowerCase.endsWith(".csv"))